Linuxのポートフォワードで外部からのアクセスを許可したい
あるアプリケーションがあり、それはローカルサーバーを起動します。
その際、リッスンするのは localhost で、ポートは 3000 番で固定です。
これはオプションにより変更はできません。
このサーバーに 80 番ポートで、同じネットワークの別の端末からのアクセスをできるようしたいです。
現在一応動く形にはできたもののあまり良い方法と思えないのでより良い手段があれば教えていただきたいです。
現在の方法は、 ssh のポートフォワード機能を使っています。
自分自身に ssh で接続し、ローカルフォワードと -g オプションを使い、 80 番ポートのアクセスを 3000 番ポートにフォワードしています。
別の試した方法ですが、 iptables や firewalld でもポートフォワードはできるようで、その環境では firewalld が有効になっていたので、 firewalld を使う方法を試してみたのですが、 firewalld を使う場合は 0.0.0.0 のリッスンとはならないようで、同端末から localhost ではアクセスできるものの外部からはアクセスできません。
なにかいい方法があれば教えていただけると幸いです。

追記）
使用するツールは、できれば RHEL 系で初期から入ってるもの、難しければ dnf にてインストール可なものとしたいです。
dnf では RHEL のパッケージと EPEL が使えます。

ポート80ということはHTTPでしょうか？ その場合は質問文へ記載ください。通常パッケージ実現するならApacheやnginxでリダイレクトするのかな。任意のTCPとなるとわかりませんし、UDPとなると無理ですね。

定番ですが、nginxはどうでしょうか？こちらは、RHELでもパッケージ(RHEL9であればnginx 1.20がフルライフサポート)が用意されています。
対象のアプリーケションが通信するプロトコルがHTTPまたはHTTPSであれば、何も問題ありません。nginxは優れたリバースプロキシを提供してくれます。さらに、HTTPをHTTPS化することもできます(stoneでも一応できるんですけど)。多くのWebアプリケーションでも使用されている一般的な方法ですので、検索すればすぐに方法が見つかるでしょう。
対象のアプリーケションが通信するプロトコルがHTTPでもHTTPSでもない場合でも安心してください。nginxのngx_stream_proxy_moduleを使えば、TCPとUDPの汎用的なリバースプロキシとしても使用できます。TCPならTLS化も可能です。もし、SMTP等のメールプロトコルなら、さらに細かい操作もできます。(実際に使うには、nginxパッケージ以外に、nginx-mod-streamパッケージも必要になると思います。)
nginxのパッケージにはsystemdのユニットファイルも付いてきますので、nginxの設定ファイルを編集して、systemctlでnginxサービスを起動すればいいだけです。あとは適当にファイアウォールをあければ、外部からもアクセスできるでしょう。
一つ注意点があります。RHELのデフォルトの状態(SE Linuxが有効、かつ、特にポリシーを変更してない)では、パッケージで入れたnginxのリバースプロキシはSE Linuxによって遮断されます。setseboolコマンドで、リバースプロキシに必要なSE Linuxのブール値をonにする必要があります。検証時にうまくいかない場合は、sudo setenforce 0でSE Linuxを一時無効にして確認してください。SE Linuxが原因なら、適切なブール値を設定してください(カスタムポリシーまで作る必要までは無かったはずです)。

ありがとうございます。なるほど、リバースプロキシを使う方法ですね。リバースプロキシはポートフォワードに比べて遠回しなやり方になるのかなと思って候補に入れてなかったですが、実現できると思いますしおすすめされる方法であればこちらで考えようと思います。

stoneを使うというのはどうでしょうか？
sudo stone -o nobody -g nogroup localhost:3000 80

※ 80をバインドするためにroot権限で動作させる必要がありますが、-oと-gで実行ユーザーを変えられます。
とすることで、80で受け付けたパケットをlocalhostの3000に飛ばします。ただ、それだけのアプリです。Ubuntuだとパッケージがあるようですが、パッケージがないディストリビューションでもGCCがあれば簡単にコンパイルできます。ただ、単純な実行ファイルとしてしか提供されていないので、サービスとして実行したいという場合は自分でsystemdのユニットファイルを用意してください。

ありがとうございます。試してみたところ期待するよう動いてそうです。しかし実際に使う箇所ではRHEL系に初期で入ってる標準的なコマンドか、dnfで入れられるRHELのパッケージ(epelなら可)くらいになりそうで、その他の方法も引き続き募集したいと思います
